# Truth tables in libreoffice calc: existence of the implies and equivalence functions?

Tags: logical-operators, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to construct a truth table in Libreoffice Calc and can't seem too find the implies- nor equivalence functions in the documentation. Do they exist and if so, what are they called?

Comment: A implies B can be expressed by not A or B and A equivalent B by A and B or not A and not B.

Comment: So essentially I have to construct the functions myself. I was hoping this wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own functions. From the menu choose "Tools" -> "Macros" -> "Organize Macros" -> "LibreOffice Basic...". In the new window choose "Tools" -> "Select Module". Create a new module or select and existing and click the "Edit" button. In the code pane you can now define your functions, for example:

```
Function IMPLIES (A As Boolean, B As Boolean) As Boolean
  IMPLIES = (NOT A) OR B
End Function

Function EQUIVALENT (A As Boolean, B As Boolean) As Boolean
  EQUIVALENT = (A AND B) OR ((NOT A) AND (NOT B))
End Function
```

Save and you can use the functions like regular functions in your sheet, e.g. `=IMPLIES(TRUE, FALSE)` or `=EQUIVALENT(FALSE, TRUE)`.